# Как подключить русские шрифты?

Tags: windows, шрифты, qtcreator, c++

Как подключить русские шрифты в qtcreator под виндовс системой (вывод в консоль)?

Вот здесь красивый развернутый ответ http://cppstudio.com/post/435/ , но он не работает, крякозяблы все равно вместо русских букв.

http://shot.qip.ru/00cqmW-6KQUSZ9T5/ (скриншот моего окна)

Comment: Вы пытаетесь вывести utf-8 строку в восьмибитной консоли (там, похоже, уже cp-1251). Правильное решение - это, конечно, перейти на нормальную ось, все проблемы решаются.

В виндовом cmd нельзя выставить юникод строкой chcp 65001.

Comment: Виндушная консоль — не очень продвинутая штука. А зачем вам она в графическом приложении? Если надо вывести лог, пишите его не на консоль, а в отдельное окно в какой-нибудь list box, и забудьте о проблемах навсегда.

Comment: Я winforms не освоил, пишу для души, да и комп старенький, новую ос не потянет. Перейду на mvs.

Comment: @perfect: А зачем winforms, если у вас Qt? Qt сам по себе отличный UI-фреймворк. (И не требовательный к ресурсам.)

Comment: Пробовал, на этой версии виджеты вообще не работают. Недопилили, а другой версии у меня нет.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить заголовочный файл  `#include <locale.h>`,
а в основной функции строчку: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");`
У меня работает.