# Аналог функции transform(, , , toupper) из стандартной библиотеки для русского языка

Tags: c++, windows, строки

Подскажите аналог функции `transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), toupper)` из стандартной библиотеки для русского языка. Английский текст преобразовывает, русский не преобразовывает.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    SetConsoleCP(1251);// установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток ввода
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток вывода

    string str = "Привет! hello";
    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), toupper);

    cout << str << 10 + 1 << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Увы, таинства окон в иной мир доступны не всем. Под линуксом mingw на эту transform откровенно матерится, а как это чудо откомпилировать в VS 2010 Express, я не знаю. Там ведь и main-то нет, какой-то _tmain ...

Comment: _tmain это протип функции main для линковки под ОС насколько я помню.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/363295/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D1%8B?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=363631#363631). Нехватало заголовка с настройками, нужно добавить `#include <locale.h>` и настройку локали `setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");`.